# Redirect plotly dash to internal link on variable set

Tags: javascript, python, html, plotly, plotly-dash

Sorry for asking this naive question, but I am really stuck with Plotly.
I want to redirect my current page on the dash to another page (internal) from an if-else statement without refresh/reload.
For example:

```
if x==0:
  --redirect to page2 in the same folder--
elif x==1:
  --redirect to page3 in the same folder--
```

Is there any easy way or one liner to do this?
I tried:

```
html.Script(type='text/javascript', src="assets/redirect.js")
```

the js file contains "windows.location.href" command. But it is not working in this way.

Any help?